# Accessing yassnippet from other editors (namely jupyter lab)

Tags: yasnippet

I spend most of my time working in emacs, but some of the time I use jupyter lab (I've played with an emacs extension to talk to jupyter from emacs but have been bitten by bugs - and I also do pairing).

It'd be cool if I could get at the collections of snippets that I built up over time in yassnippet. Is there a way to access snippets from other editors, or even just put them on the clipboard?